# How to validate excel data when I import using SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have one Excel file, in that file have 3 column.

Eg;

```
ModelNo Cost Quantity
 1       2.00  4
 2       3     0
 3       4     Null
 4       3     1
 5       7     null
```

Now I want to import these data into a SQL table.

When quantity is null not insert into table we send all record as mail.

The quantity is not null I want to insert record into SQL Server 
table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use DFT Conditional Split in data flow task, as follows...then in the control flow email the NULL rcords that are stored in the "null value" table.

[image]